# Blocking user in XMPP Framework iOS

Tags: iphone, xmpp

I am developing a XMPP based chat application for iOS. One of the features of the app is that i need to block some of the users from my rooster.Is there any method available to this in the XMPP framework ? If not, is there some work around to do this ?

Also can some one help me in sending images from one user to other using XMPP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of things you might want to consider:

Likely your user is subscribed to the contact's presence and vice-versa. He will unsubscribe from the contact's presence (so he will no longer receive presence notifications **from** him) by sending:

```
<presence to='contact@example.com' type='unsubscribe'/>
```

He will revoke subscription to **his** own presence from the contact by sending:

```
<presence to='contact@example.com' type='unsubscribed'/>
```

Finally you can remove the item from your roster.

```
<iq from='user@example.com/home' type='set' id='roster'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'>
    <item jid='contact@example.com' subscription='remove'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

In fact, if you send the stanza above, i.e. if you want to cancel *both* subscriptions, you do not need to send the presence stanzas, they will be handled by the servers.

Finally, you can now block further interaction with the user by means of the `jabber:iq:privacy` API. This is explained in detail [here](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#privacy).

The general presence/roster management is explained in the same rfc, probably best [here](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#int).

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code to implement user blocking:

```
-(void)blockUser{

XMPPIQ *iq = [[XMPPIQ alloc]init];
NSString *from = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"from@mail.com/resources"];

[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue: from];

[iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];

NSXMLElement *block =[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"block" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:blocking"];

NSXMLElement *item = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"item"];

[item addAttributeWithName:@"jid" stringValue:@"to@mail.com/resources"];

[block addChild:item];

[iq addChild:block];

[xmppStream sendElement:iq];

}
```

Comment: @Preetha which XMPP server you are using ? this code is not working for me i am using Openfire 4.1.1.

Comment: I used ejabberd chat server

Comment: @Preetha did you get any solution for block and unblock user.? please help to find it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46155095/2910061

Answer (score -1):

```
    - (void)setupXMPPPrivacy
{
NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] "), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
//Init XMPPPrivacy List
//xmppPrivacy = [[XMPPPrivacy alloc] init];
xmppPrivacy = [[XMPPPrivacy alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
//Activate xmpp modules
[xmppPrivacy activate:[[self appDelegate] xmppStream]];
//Delegate XMPPPrivacy
[xmppPrivacy addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppPrivacy retrieveListWithName :@"Block_List"];

}

-(void)privacyblock
{

[xmppPrivacy retrieveListWithName:@"Block_List"];
    [xmppPrivacy setActiveListName:@"Block_List"];
    NSXMLElement *privacyElement = [XMPPPrivacy privacyItemWithType:@"jid" value:xmpp_jid action:@"deny" order:1];
    [XMPPPrivacy blockIQs:privacyElement];
    [XMPPPrivacy blockMessages:privacyElement];
    [XMPPPrivacy blockPresenceIn:privacyElement];
    [XMPPPrivacy blockPresenceOut:privacyElement];

    NSLog(@"-------> PRIVACY ELEMENT: %@", privacyElement);

    [arrayPrivacy addObject:privacyElement];
    [xmppPrivacy setListWithName:@"Block_List" items:arrayPrivacy];

}
```

Comment: Code only answers aren't very good, recommend you explain this.

Comment: just import xmppprivacy.h file .create privacy Block_list using this code and send iq to get that Block list using  [xmppPrivacy retrieveListWithName :@"Block_List"]; this method.

Comment: Once this code is executed at that time user not received message form blocked user but when i reconnect my xmppstream i'm getting message from blocked user.